# L'anglicisme « efficient » a-t-il un sens que ne couvre pas « efficace »?

Tags: emprunts, anglicismes

L'adjectif *[efficient](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efficient)* a deux sens en français : un sens technique, du domaine de la philosophie (« possédant la qualité de produire un effet »), et un sens commun, emprunt à l'anglais apparu au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Le *Trésor de la langue française* note, comme tous les dictionnaires que j'ai sous la main, que dans son second sens le mot *efficient* est synonyme avec *efficace*. Or, je suis surpris que les deux mots coexistent si leurs sens sont si peu distincts. Ma question est donc : **en quoi *efficient* diffère-t-il d'*efficace* ?**

La raison qui me fait poser cette question est que j'ai l'impression que l'usage d'*efficient* est en augmentation, notamment dans du « technospeak managerial » du genre « une gouvernance d'entreprise efficiente »…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Efficient* en anglais a une notion de moyen proportionné aux résultats qu'*efficace* en français n'a pas (son sens est un de ceux d'*effective* en anglais, il ne considère que le résultat).

L'utilisation d'*efficient* en français est d'après les lexicographes (et un exemple comme celui de la citation de [Camus dans le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efficient) montre qu'ils ont des raisons de le penser) plus proche d'efficace que du sens anglais, même si une nuance pas encore bien fixée est en cours d'élaboration.

Il est possible, sinon probable, qu'une partie des gens employant *efficient* le font avec le sens anglais (ce n'est vraisemblablement pas limité aux gestionnaires, la nuance est importante aussi pour les ingénieurs et les deux groupes sont sous forte influence d'une littérature rédigée en anglais).

Il est intéressant de comparer avec [efficience](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efficience) qui acquiert aussi une nouvelle acception sous l'influence de l'anglais, mais pour lequel le sens d'*efficiency* (et donc la considération des moyens employés pour obtenir le résultat) est bien observée par les rédacteurs du TLFi.

Comment: Exactement. En anglais un moteur peut-être *effective*, puisqu'il permet de faire avancer la voiture, sans pour autant être *efficient*, s'il faut mettre 20 litres d'essence pour faire 100km!

Comment: Alors ce serait ça ? efficient = efficace + econome ? J'avais toujours cru à la fameuse influence technospeak pour l'usage de ce terme, mais je reconnais maintenant qu'il y a une différence de sens. Merci pour cette utile question/réponse!

Comment: Non, on ne dit qu'un moteur est ***effective***. A motor is said to be fuel ***efficient*** c'est-à-dire: économe. But, he is an efficient employee, c'est un employé efficace. That is an effective policy: C'est une politique qui donne des résultats.

Answer (score 6):

Hors abus de langage (type "technospeak managerial"), je pense que traduire "*efficient*" par "efficace" est une erreur, voire un contresens.

Anglicisme ou pas, [le concept technique d'efficience est différent de l'efficacité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficience). L'anglais "*computationally efficient*", par exemple ne saurait mettre en cause "l'efficacité" du-dit algorithme/programme, mais uniquement sa capacité à être exécuté dans des conditions de ressources données.

Malgré de possibles abus, je pense que "efficient" est un néologisme incontournable (et peu choquant, vu les origines latines du mot) qu'il serait absurde de chercher à plaquer sur "efficace" (qui a déjà "*effective*" en anglais).

Answer (score 4):

*Efficace* indique que cela permet d'atteindre le résultat souhaité. C'est un état binaire, au sens ou quelque chose est efficace ou pas.

*Efficient* indique qu'en plus d'être efficace, les ressources ont été bien utilisées (c'est subjectif, je sais.) C'est un attribut graduel, au sens ou quelque chose peut être plus, ou moins, efficient.

Exemple : Planter un clou de finition avec une masse est efficace. Planter un clou de finition avec un marteau est cependant plus efficient.

Comment: Efficace n'est pas binaire. On dit bien que telle chose est plus efficace qu'une autre. Croyez bien que les français n'ont pas attendu l'anglais pour discuter de l'*efficiency* des choses. Bien évidement toutes les langues doivent avoir un terme similaire.

Comment: @Bobog : *Bien évidemment* ? [citation needed] ! Par ailleurs, il me semble que **par rapport** à *efficient*, *efficace* est bien binaire, ou qu'en tout cas, celà contribue à discerner la différence.

Answer (score 1):

[L'emploi récent par extension est généralement jugé avec sévérité comme un anglicisme de sens, synonyme de *efficace* ; il semble cependant parfois que le champ sémantique de *efficient* soit plus restreint dans cet emploi que celui de *efficace*, et corresponde à un effet s'exerçant dans un cas particulier ou dans un secteur déterminé.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efficient)

En d'autres mots (les miens cette fois), *efficace* était le seul mot utilisé auparavant, mais sa traduction anglaise *efficient* a percolé dans le language français au point de devenir acceptée. Le fait qu'elle soit moins courante, et considérée par beaucoup comme un anglicisme (spontanément, j'aurais aussi dit « Non, ce n'est pas un mot correct » moi-même), est sans doute ce qui donne l'impression de différence.

Comment: J'avoue avoir du mal à suivre la différence proposée. Pourrais-tu donner des exemples différançiant les deux ?

Comment: J'ai bien dit _impression_ de différence. Pour moi, la seule différence jusqu'à il y a 20 minutes était « _efficient_ n'existe pas en français, utilisez _efficace_ ». Maintenant, si je devais en faire une, je lierais ça à la notion de temps : pour moi, _efficace_ est absolu, tandis qu'_efficent_ est plus ponctuel, dans le sens « c'est efficace _maintenant_ ». Mais à nouveau, c'est plus une impression qu'autre chose. En tous cas, je rejoins l'avis du TLF sur un point: _efficient_ est plus restreint qu'_efficace_, qui peut toujours être utilisé en lieu et place d'_efficient_.

Answer (score 0):

En physique il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté sur l'efficacité, c'est bien un résultat sous contrainte de moyens, dont l'exacte traduction en Anglais est Efficiciency.

Nos amis Anglais ont la chance d'avoir un vocabulaire plus riche que nous :
-Efficiency
-Effectiveness
-Efficacy
Que nous avons tous traduit par efficacité en Français, en bref, nous sommes pauvres.

Answer (score 0):

*Efficient* a aussi un sens technique en philosophie, où l'on trouve l'expression *cause efficiente* dans la [philosophie d'Aristote](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Th%C3%A9orie_aristot%C3%A9licienne_de_la_causalit%C3%A9).